# AWS: CloudWatch idle time alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an EC2 instance where I use Jenkins continuous integration server.

I only start it when necessary, and to avoid forgetting to shutdown, I created a cloud watch alarm to stop it if maximum of CPU utilization is <= 30 for 1 hour.

But sometimes a few minutes after the instance is started the cloud watch alarm stops it.

My guess is that it's considering the time that the instance was stopped in the alarm data calculation.

Is there a way to start counting the idle time only after the instance was started?

Thanks